# How would a person live on a gas giant?

Tags: habitability

I had an idea of a character in my story living on the bottom of the upper atmosphere in some sort of space station or ship. Would living like this in a gas giant be possible like on Bespin from Star Wars

[image: This is my idea for what the planet looks like]

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. We have a one question per post policy, since it makes easier to pick good answers. Please edit the post accordingly. You can find more info in the [help]

Comment: You might find [The Algeraist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Algebraist) , by Iain M. Banks of interest.

Comment: One thing to consider: I think there is a non-zero chance that a terrestrial human may be driven insane by the view. No, I'm not kidding: see Thalassophobia and Acrophobia. But imagine that instead of a big opaque ocean, it's an almost unimaginably colossal, ever-changing, mostly-transparent pocket of unsurvivable atmosphere... which rests on top of an exotic "ocean."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Khaoskaphe**

[image: xkcd]

from Jupiter Submarine. https://what-if.xkcd.com/138/

Your character inhabits a khaoskaphe - a vehicle capable of traversing the various layers of the gas giant atmosphere.  You can keep Lobot from Bespin since he seems like a handy person to have around but the ability to visit various layers each with their own inhabitants and ecosystem will make it more fun for the fiction.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a [balloon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balloon) is perfectly possible, though you are somewhat limited in the choice of buoyant gas, realistically only heated hydrogen.

Less realistic, but cooler is a [supramundane shell](http://www.orionsarm.com/fm_store/SupramundanePlanets.pdf) over the planet.

Comment: What an excellent paper!